# External javascript loads but doesn't execute

Tags: javascript, html

So I'm trying to serve a simple web page. In my html I have a form and I'd like to simply say no results found when anything is searched for. If I place a javascript function into script tags into the html document the div gets populated. However whenever I use an external js file it isn't even executed. The console logs nothing and no alerts show up. The server is serving up these files however because if I log the request URL I see that /button_click.js is being served. Can someone explain why this happens? Here is my code for reference:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

 <html>
   <head>
     <style>
        body{background: skyblue; font-family: verdana; color: #fff; padding: 30px;}
        h1{font-size: 48px; text-transform: uppercase; letter-spacing: 2px; text-align:center;}
        p{font-size: 16px; text-align:center;}
      </style>

      <script type="text/javascript" src="button_click.js">
        // if uncommented and without the src tag this seems to do the job
        // function buttonClick() {
        //   document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = "No results found";
        //   return false;
        // }
      </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1> Welcome to the home page</h1>
    <form id="form" onsubmit="return buttonClick()">
      <input type="text" name="search"> <br>
      <input type="submit" name="submit"> <br>
    </form>

    <p id = "result">
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

**button_click.js**

```
function buttonClick() {
  console.log('in here');
  alert("in here");
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = "No results found";
  return false;
}
```

**UPDATE**

My console gives me an unexpected token for "<" error at line 1 in my js file. When I do try and check the file through the browsers resources the js file is apparently exactly the same as my index.html file. It contains no javascript and has the contents of index.html. Why is this?

All my files are in the same directory and I have checked all the file names as well.Here are the contents of my server file for reference:

**server.js**

```
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');


const server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  res.writeHeader(200, {"Content_Type": "text/html"});
  var readStream = fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/index.html', 'utf8');
  readStream.pipe(res);
  console.log(req.url);
  console.log('served page');
});

server.listen(3000, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Listening in port 3000');
```

Comment: The content between script tags is ignored, if a src attribute is present, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script

Comment: have you checked in browsers console for any error?

Comment: Surround button_click.js's content in `document.onload();` and test if it works. Or put your script tag before `</body>` tag

Comment: The script works fine between the script tags. It is when I use a src attribute that it does not work. When I try to execute the code from between the script tags I remove the src attribute so as to not cause any conflicts and it works.

Comment: You can't get both, inline script and external in the same tag. Please read the documentation I've linked above.

Comment: @BehradKhodayarI tried both of those and it still doesn't edit the div element.

Comment: @Teemu he says that if he comments out the inline script, the external script doesnt work.

Comment: @Teemu I don't use both together. If I use an external script I remove the inline script even the comments. If I use the inline script I remove the src attribute and then it works.

Comment: If it's on your domain root directory:  <script type="text/JavaScript" src="/button_click.js"></script>

Comment: @CaptainMagikarp adding a slash in front of button_click doesn't work

Comment: I suspect you have a typo in the file name, or the `js` file is not in the same folder as your `index.html`. Please check carefully you spelled `button_click.js` the same way as the filename on your server. The reason `index.html` content shows up, could be a "feature" of the server when it cannot locate a file: it then defaults to `index.html`.

Comment: @trincot I checked the file names and all my files are in the same directory. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you added the content of `server.js` to your question, it becomes clear what has happened.

The callback to `http.createServer` is called for *every* request. And you actually modify the normal response like this:

```
var readStream = fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/index.html', 'utf8');
readStream.pipe(res);
```

... which explains why your request for `button_click.js` results in the content of the index page coming back, giving the behaviour you describe.

So remove those two lines and it should work a lot better.

See also the [`nodejs`](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/anatomy-of-an-http-transaction/) documentation on this.

NB: If you want to force `index.html` to be returned in *some* situations, then perform the necessary filtering on the `url` before executing those lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

This is you code but it is not working when function called in `form.onsubmit`.

```js
function buttonClick() {
  console.log('in here');
  alert("in here");
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = "No results found";
  return false;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

 <html>
   <head>
     <style>
        body{background: skyblue; font-family: verdana; color: #fff; padding: 30px;}
        h1{font-size: 48px; text-transform: uppercase; letter-spacing: 2px; text-align:center;}
        p{font-size: 16px; text-align:center;}
      </style>
 </head>

  <body>
    <h1> Welcome to the home page</h1>
    <form id="form" onsubmit="return buttonClick()">
      <input type="text" name="search"> <br>
      <input type="submit" name="submit"> <br>
    </form>

    <p id = "result">
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

This Code works when function calling from `input[type=submit]`.

```js
function buttonClick() {
  console.log('in here');
  alert("in here");
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = "No results found";
  return false;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

 <html>
   <head>
     <style>
        body{background: skyblue; font-family: verdana; color: #fff; padding: 30px;}
        h1{font-size: 48px; text-transform: uppercase; letter-spacing: 2px; text-align:center;}
        p{font-size: 16px; text-align:center;}
      </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1> Welcome to the home page</h1>
    <form id="form" >
      <input type="text" name="search"> <br>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" onclick="buttonClick();"> <br>
    </form>

    <p id = "result">
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This doesn't work. Even when I put the javascript code inline the onclick causes the page to refresh. When I keep the javascript code in a separate file the onclick does not show any alerts or change the divs inner html